# Why does QProcess returns Starting state even after killing the process?

Tags: python, pyqt, qprocess

I cannot understand why the program is returning starting state value which is 1 even after killing it.

Before starting it, it gives 0 value which is NotRunning and after starting it it gives 1.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
self.p = QProcess()
print("before start state: ", self.p.state())
self.p.start("python", ['run.py'])
print("after start state: ", self.p.state())

self.p.kill()
p = self.p.state()
print("after kill state: ", p)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the `QProcess` doesn't start/finish immediately after calling `start/kill`, you should connect to `Qprocess::started()` and `Qprocess::finished(int exitCode, QProcess::ExitStatus exitStatus = NormalExit)` signals.

Comment: I see, but how would I do this in python coding because as I recall there is no started and finished function? I am using linux with python coding.

Comment: @C137 That style of connection syntax isn't valid in PyQt5/6. It must be done like this: `process.started.connect(slot)`. The slot can be any kind of python callable object, so the OP's example would look like this: `self.p.started.connect(lambda: print("before start state: ", self.p.state()))`.

Comment: Sorry but I don't usually use `pyqt` I just googled it and copy-pasted from the link. I will delete my comment.

Comment: @ekhumoro I see, yeah that is why I was getting Attributeerror